# how import erc20 from paper wallet to online wallet eg my ether

Tags: erc-20

does anyone know how to get my Theta (erc20 ) tokens off a paper wallet back online coinomi cant do it maybe my ether? struggling to find any where to put a private key off my paper wallet so i can transfer onto an online wallet can anyone help thank you

Comment: Use MyCrypto.com and choose the private key option